# not enough arguments for method when: Spark/scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Dataframes in spark Df1 and Df2 i am joining these 2 Dataframes based on one common column i.e. Id ,and then added one extra column result and checking multiple column with or condition if any of column data matched then i need to insert in new column as matched and if no condition matched then need to pass as 'Not Matched' in that column. I am writing below code.

```
    df1.join(df1,df2("id") === df2("id"))
   .withColumn("Result",
   when(
   df1("adhar_no") === df2("adhar_no")" || 
   df1("pan_no") === df2("pan_no") || 
   df1("Voter_id") === df2("Voter_id") || 
   df1("DL_no") === df2("DL_no"),"Matched"
  ).otherwise("Not Matched"))

  But getting error

  <console>:60: error: not enough arguments for method when: (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column. Unspecified value parameter value.

  I have also tried below code

    df1.join(df2,df1("id") === df2("id"))
   .withColumn("Result",when(df1("adhar_no") === df2("adhar_no") || 
   when(df1("pan_no") === df2("pan_no") || 
   when(df1("Voter_id") === df2("Voter_id") ||  
   when(df1("DL_no") === df2("DL_no"),"Matched"))))
  .otherwise("Not Matched"))
```

In both the cases i am getting error can anyone plase help how should i do this.

Comment: you are joining same df1.join(df1) how you are accessing df2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The first case it's because you have an extra `"` on line 4 (first when condition)

This will work just fine:

```
 df1.join(df2,df2("id") === df2("id"))
   .withColumn("Result",
   when(
   df1("adhar_no") === df2("adhar_no") || 
   df1("pan_no") === df2("pan_no") || 
   df1("Voter_id") === df2("Voter_id") || 
   df1("DL_no") === df2("DL_no"),"Matched"
  ).otherwise("Not Matched"))
```

The second one is beacause each when must have an output value:  that example makes no sense for me. The first one is just fine but you need to remove yout extra " (I assume is a type)

Aslo, as a personal preference or recommendation, i'd rather to reference the column with the dollar syntax. It's way clearer for me and helps me to avoid such typos

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE**

Some crappy test dataframes

```
   val df1 = List((1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000), (3, 30, 300, 3000, 30000)).toDF("id","adhar_no", "pan_no", "Voter_id", "DL_no")
    val df2 = List((1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000), (4, 40, 400, 4000, 40000)).toDF("id","adhar_no", "pan_no", "Voter_id", "DL_no")
```

And then, your code with ambiguities fixed:

```
 df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"), df1("id") === df2("id"))
      .withColumn("Result",  when(
          $"df1.adhar_no" === $"df2.adhar_no" ||
            $"df1.pan_no" === $"df2.pan_no" ||
            $"df1.Voter_id" === $"df2.Voter_id" ||
            $"df1.DL_no" === $"df2.DL_no"
          , "Matched"
        ).otherwise("Not Matched")
      )
+---+--------+------+--------+-----+---+--------+------+--------+-----+-------+
| id|adhar_no|pan_no|Voter_id|DL_no| id|adhar_no|pan_no|Voter_id|DL_no| Result|
+---+--------+------+--------+-----+---+--------+------+--------+-----+-------+
|  1|      10|   100|    1000|10000|  1|      10|   100|    1000|10000|Matched|
|  2|      20|   200|    2000|20000|  2|      20|   200|    2000|20000|Matched|
+---+--------+------+--------+-----+---+--------+------+--------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Yes it was typo I have updated the code but i m getting same error.

Comment: It's working fine for me after fixing some other errors, i'll update my answer with an example

Comment: @ SCouto Yes its worked.. Thanks a lot  SCouto. I have one more doubt I am trying to implemnt some more cases like when in both the column name is null  null then it shold give not matched I have writing like this..withColumn("result", when(df1("name") === df2("id")|| (df1("name") is null && df2("name") is null,"Not matched")).otherwise("Matched")). but its showing not found &&.